# Python function with multiple parameter brackets

Tags: python

Having python code like that which is only an idea:

```
def f(a):
    def g(b):
        def h(c):
            return a + b - c
        return h
    return g
print(f(2)(3)(4))    # 1
```

Is it possible to modify above code to write a function which allowed for that?

```
f(7) -> 7
f(1)(2)(3) -> 1 + 2 - 3 -> 0
f(-5)(10)(3)(9) -> -5 + 10 - 3 + 9 -> 11
```

Comment: I for one do not understand what you are asking ... but the answer is assuredly yes whatever you are trying to do is possible (ish)

Comment: This depends on what *exactly* you're trying to do in the real code. You could have it return a function object that can be treated as an integer, but you can't have just a plain int since it would also need to be callable in case the caller wants to add more arguments.

Comment: Why do you need the brackets? What's wrong with using one function with a variable number of arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a callable class instead of a function it's possible to do something like this, which will produce the desired output for the two cases you supplied:

```
class f:
    def __init__(self, value, multi=1):
        self.value = value
        self.multi = multi

    def __call__(self, value):
        return f(self.value + (value * self.multi), self.multi * -1)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

print(f(1)(2)(3))
print(f(-5)(10)(3)(9))
```

Comment: This is what I expected. I'm curious how you could do something like this in c++ or java. There is no __call__ method, but that's another question:-)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to create a function with optional arguments?
If yes, you could use *args.

For example:

```
def fun(a, *args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        return a + args[0]
    elif len(args) == 2:
        return a + args[0] - args[1]
    else:
        return a
```

Another solution could be using prenamed optional arguments arguments:

```
def foo(a, b=None, c=None):
    if b:
        return a + b
    elif b and c:
        return a + b - c
    else:
        return a

print(foo(1, 2, 3))
>>>3
print(fun(7))
>>>7
```